# Back4App and android studio , How to properly save a ParseObject Error

Tags: java, android-studio, save, back4app

This is the error I've run into and there seem to be no proper fixes to this code since my understanding of the back4app and android studio is very limited (com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to encode an unsaved ParseFile.).
Some of the solution I've tried was not doable and it seem to be that the ParseFile wasn't saved properly. I've tried the callback function and progress function but it doesn't seem to work. So at this point I'm out of idea on how to fix this
here is the code for my compose fragment

```
package com.example.rentahome.fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.ImageDecoder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.rentahome.ImageFilePath;
import com.example.rentahome.Post;
import com.example.rentahome.R;
import com.example.rentahome.Reviews;
import com.example.rentahome.databinding.FragmentComposeBinding;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseRelation;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.ProgressCallback;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;
import static com.parse.Parse.getApplicationContext;

public class ComposeFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 43;
    public static final int PICK_PHOTO_CODE = 21;

    private File photoFile;
    FragmentComposeBinding fragmentComposeBinding;
    private String photoFileName = "photo.jpg";
    public String realPath = new String();
    public static final String TAG = "ComposeFragment";

    public ComposeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_compose, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        fragmentComposeBinding = FragmentComposeBinding.bind(view);
        fragmentComposeBinding.btnPicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadImage();
            }
        });

        fragmentComposeBinding.btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String address = fragmentComposeBinding.etAddress.getText().toString();
                String price = fragmentComposeBinding.etPrice.getText().toString();
                String description = fragmentComposeBinding.etDescription.getText().toString();
                if(address.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Address cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(price.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Price cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(description.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Description cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(realPath == null || fragmentComposeBinding.ivPostImage.getDrawable()==null){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"There is no image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                savePost(address, price, description, currentUser);
            }
        });
    }

    private void uploadImage() {
        // create Intent to upload a picture and return control to the calling application
        // Edit action for MediaStore


        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        // Create a File reference for future access
        //photoFile = getPhotoFileUri(photoFileName);

        // wrap File object into a content provider
        // required for API >= 24
        // See https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sharing-Content-with-Intents#sharing-files-with-api-24-or-higher
        //Uri fileProvider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.example.rentahome.fileprovider", photoFile);
        //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileProvider);

        // If you call startActivityForResult() using an intent that no app can handle, your app will crash.
        // So as long as the result is not null, it's safe to use the intent.
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Start the image pick intent to pick photo from external folder
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PHOTO_CODE);
        }
    }
    public Bitmap loadFromUri(Uri photoUri) {
        Bitmap image = null;
        try {
            // check version of Anrdoid on device
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 27) {
                // newer version
                ImageDecoder.Source source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.getContext().getContentResolver(), photoUri);
                image = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source);
            } else {
                //support older
                image = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContext().getContentResolver(),photoUri);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return image;
    }

    private File getPhotoFileUri(String fileName) {
        // Get safe storage directory for photos
        // Use `getExternalFilesDir` on Context to access package-specific directories.
        // This way, we don't need to request external read/write runtime permissions.
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), TAG);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists() && !mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d(TAG, "failed to create directory..");
        }

        // Return the file target for the photo based on filename
        File file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + fileName);

        return file;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();


            realPath = ImageFilePath.getPath(getContext(), data.getData());
//                realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(this, data.getData());

            Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: file path : " + realPath);
            Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: file path : " + getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() );
            try {

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
                // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));
                fragmentComposeBinding.ivPostImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

//        if ((data != null) && requestCode == PICK_PHOTO_CODE) {
//            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
//                Uri photoUri = data.getData();
//                // by this point we have the camera photo on disk
//                //Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile.getAbsolutePath());
//                //Load the image located at photoUri into selectedImage
//                Bitmap selectedImage = loadFromUri(photoUri);
//                // RESIZE BITMAP, see section below
//                // Load the taken image into a preview
//                fragmentComposeBinding.ivPostImage.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
//
//            } else { // Result was a failure
//                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Image not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        }
    }



    private void savePost(String address, String price, String description, ParseUser currentUser) {
        //Post post = new Post();
        ParseObject post = ParseObject.create("Post");

        File file = new File(realPath);


        ParseFile photo = new ParseFile(file);

        photo.saveInBackground();
//        post.setImage(photo);
//        int parsed_price = Integer.parseInt(price);
//        post.setPrice(parsed_price);
//        post.setDescription(description);
//        post.setUser(currentUser);
//        post.setAddress(address);
//        //photo.saveInBackground();
        ParseRelation<ParseObject> hi;
        //parse String price to int..
        post.put("image",photo);
        post.put("description",description);
        post.put("address",address);
        post.put("user",currentUser);
        post.put("price",price);
        //post.put("Reviews",hi);

//        Reviews gameScore = new Reviews();
//
//        gameScore.setlikesCount(0);
//        gameScore.setdislikesCount(0);
//        gameScore.setAuthor(currentUser);
//        gameScore.setRating((float) (5.0));
//        gameScore.setDescription("hi");
////
////        gameScore.put("Description","Hi ");
////        gameScore.put("author",currentUser);
////        gameScore.put("rating",(float)(5.0));
////        gameScore.put("likesCount",0);
////        gameScore.put("dislikesCount",0);
//
//        ParseRelation<Reviews> temp = new ParseRelation<Reviews>();
//        temp.add(gameScore);

        post.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if(e!=null){
                    Log.e(TAG,"Issue with saving posts..", e);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error while saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                Log.i(TAG,"Saved successfully!");
                fragmentComposeBinding.etDescription.setText("");
                fragmentComposeBinding.ivPostImage.setImageResource(0);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Here is my post class, and one of the special thing about it was the relation I have inside the post class. There is a reviews relation which contain objects reviews

```
package com.example.rentahome;

import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseRelation;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@ParseClassName("Post")
public class Post extends ParseObject {
    public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";     //image should be 'uploaded'
    public static final String KEY_USER = "user";
    public static final String KEY_CREATED_KEY = "createdAt"; //have to figure out how to implement
    public static final String KEY_address = "address";
    public static final String KEY_price = "price";
    public static final String KEY_reviews = "Reviews";
    public static final String KEY_objectID = "objectID";

    public String getDescription(){
        return getString(KEY_DESCRIPTION);
    }
    public void setDescription(String description){
        put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
    }

    public ParseFile getImage(){
        return getParseFile(KEY_IMAGE);
    }
    public void setImage(ParseFile parseFile){
        put(KEY_IMAGE, parseFile);
    }

    public ParseUser getUser(){
        return getParseUser(KEY_USER);
    }
    public void setUser(ParseUser user){put(KEY_USER, user);}

    public String getAddress() {return getString(KEY_address);}
    public void setAddress(String address){ put(KEY_address, address);}

    public int getPrice(){return getInt(KEY_price);}
    public void setPrice(int price){put(KEY_price,price);}
    public String getobjectID(){return getString(KEY_objectID);}

    public ParseRelation<ParseObject>  getrelation() {return getRelation(KEY_reviews);}
    public void setrelation(ParseRelation<ParseObject>  relation){put(KEY_reviews, relation);}

    //public ParseRelation<ParseObject> getReviews(){return getRelation(KEY_reviews);}
    //public void setReviews(ParseRelation<ParseObject> reviews){put(KEY_reviews, reviews);}

    //public Date getCreatedAt() { return getDate(KEY_CREATED_KEY);}
```

My review class

```
package com.example.rentahome;

import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

@ParseClassName("Reviews")
public class Reviews extends ParseObject {
    public static final String KEY_author = "author";
    public static final String KEY_description = "Description";
    public static final String KEY_likesCount = "likesCount";
    public static final String KEY_dislikesCount = "dislikesCount";
    public static final String KEY_rating = "rating";



    public String getDescription(){return getString(KEY_description);}
    public void setDescription(String description){put(KEY_description, description);}
    public ParseUser getAuthor(){return getParseUser(KEY_author); }
    public void setAuthor(ParseUser author){put(KEY_author,author);}
    public float getRating(){return (float)getDouble(KEY_rating);}
    public void setRating(float rating) {put(KEY_rating, rating);}
    public int getlikesCount() {return getInt(KEY_likesCount);}
    public void setlikesCount(int likesCount){put(KEY_likesCount, likesCount);}
    public int getdislikesCount() {return getInt(KEY_dislikesCount);}
    public void setdislikesCount(int dislikesCount){put(KEY_dislikesCount, dislikesCount);}
}
```

Here is the error message

```
E/ComposeFragment: Issue with saving posts..
    com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to encode an unsaved ParseFile.
        at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:119)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to encode an unsaved ParseFile.
        at com.parse.ParseFile.encode(ParseFile.java:653)
        at com.parse.ParseEncoder.encode(ParseEncoder.java:77)
        at com.parse.ParseSetOperation.encode(ParseSetOperation.java:31)
        at com.parse.ParseEncoder.encode(ParseEncoder.java:126)
        at com.parse.ParseObjectCoder.encode(ParseObjectCoder.java:57)
        at com.parse.NetworkObjectController.saveAsync(NetworkObjectController.java:60)
        at com.parse.ParseObject$32.then(ParseObject.java:2282)
        at com.parse.ParseObject$32.then(ParseObject.java:2277)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15.run(Task.java:907)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:113)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:898)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:713)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:724)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$13.then(Task.java:816)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$13.then(Task.java:804)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15.run(Task.java:907)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:113)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:898)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.access$100(Task.java:28)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$11.then(Task.java:706)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$11.then(Task.java:703)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:946)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.trySetResult(Task.java:984)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:45)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:68)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:924)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:911)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$14.run(Task.java:866)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:113)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:857)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.continueWith(Task.java:659)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.continueWith(Task.java:670)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15.run(Task.java:911)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:113)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:898)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.access$100(Task.java:28)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$11.then(Task.java:706)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$11.then(Task.java:703)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:946)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.trySetResult(Task.java:984)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:45)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:68)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$8.then(Task.java:562)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$8.then(Task.java:536)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$14.run(Task.java:866)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:113)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:857)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.access$000(Task.java:28)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$10.then(Task.java:652)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$10.then(Task.java:649)
E/ComposeFragment:     at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:946)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.trySetResult(Task.java:984)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.trySetResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:45)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.setResult(TaskCompletionSource.java:68)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$14.run(Task.java:867)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:113)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:857)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.access$000(Task.java:28)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$10.then(Task.java:652)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$10.then(Task.java:649)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:946)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.trySetError(Task.java:1001)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(TaskCompletionSource.java:52)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.setError(TaskCompletionSource.java:77)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$8.then(Task.java:552)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$8.then(Task.java:536)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$14.run(Task.java:866)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:113)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:857)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.access$000(Task.java:28)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$10.then(Task.java:652)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$10.then(Task.java:649)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:946)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.trySetError(Task.java:1001)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(TaskCompletionSource.java:52)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.setError(TaskCompletionSource.java:77)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:922)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:911)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$14.run(Task.java:866)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:113)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:857)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.access$000(Task.java:28)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$10.then(Task.java:652)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$10.then(Task.java:649)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:946)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.trySetError(Task.java:1001)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(TaskCompletionSource.java:52)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.setError(TaskCompletionSource.java:77)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:922)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:911)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$14.run(Task.java:866)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:113)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:857)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.continueWith(Task.java:659)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.continueWith(Task.java:670)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15.run(Task.java:911)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:113)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:898)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.access$100(Task.java:28)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$11.then(Task.java:706)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$11.then(Task.java:703)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.runContinuations(Task.java:946)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.trySetError(Task.java:1001)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.trySetError(TaskCompletionSource.java:52)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.TaskCompletionSource.setError(TaskCompletionSource.java:77)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:922)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15$1.then(Task.java:911)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$14.run(Task.java:866)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:113)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.completeImmediately(Task.java:857)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.continueWith(Task.java:659)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task.continueWith(Task.java:670)
        at com.parse.boltsinternal.Task$15.run(Task.java:911)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem happens because you are not awaiting `photo.saveInBackground` to complete. Your code should look like this:

```java
ParseObject post = ParseObject.create("Post");
File file = new File(realPath);
ParseFile photo = new ParseFile(file);
photo.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
   @Override
   public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
       // Handle success or failure here ...
       post.put("image",photo);
       post.put("description",description);
       post.put("address",address);
       post.put("user",currentUser);
       post.put("price",price);
    
       post.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
           @Override
           public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
               // Handle success or failure here ...
           }
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the solution didn't work for me. Still the same error after I've put the code and replace it. Still saying java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to encode an unsaved ParseFile. I think it could be something wrong with the File instead.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `e` ? Maybe the first request is failing.

Comment: The issue is resolved. The pathing was wrong! haha is on my end Your code worked perfectly fine